# Need Clarity on Chartjs - Asp.NetMVC or Vue-ChartJS -Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js, chart.js

I am new in Coding world. I have a assignment where we are using Asp.net MVC  along with Chartjs and Vuejs.

I am currently looking at examples using chartjs in ASP.Net MVC and making mockup.

How different it would be if I incorporate Vue.js later...will it would be different syntax altogether.

Need help in understanding the difference.

Thanks.

Conceptual understanding needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very open but I'll try giving you the concept:

I've not worked with ASP.NET MVC but I assume it could work like any other backend framework and Vue is your frontend.

You can move data back and forth from your backend(ASP.net which interfaces with your database) using a simple api which vue can utilize/consume.

1. Try setting up your ASP.NET with Vue first. You can see [this](https://intellitect.com/quickly-configure-asp-net-core-api-to-work-with-vue-cli-3/) or any other example from online.
2. Add [chartjs](https://alligator.io/vuejs/vue-chart-js/) to your vue frontend consuming the data from your backend.